# How to know the max value of a Object in Razor ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have in my html :

```
@foreach (Artist artist in Model.artist)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@artist.attr.rank</td>
        <td><a href="@artist.url" target="_blank">@artist.name</a></td>
        <td><div ... aria-valuenow="@artist.playcount" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="???">@artist.playcount</div></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Where Mode.artist is :

```
public List<Artist> artist { get; set; }
```

And a Artist is defined like that :

```
public class Artist
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int playcount { get; set; }
    public string mbid { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string streamable { get; set; }
    public List<Image> image { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@attr")]
    public Rank attr { get; set; }
}
```

I want that the aria-valuemax="???" to be the max value for all the artists
How do I do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
...aria-valuemax="@Model.artist.Max(x=> x.playcount)"...
```

But, it would be better to declare this as variable ***outside of the loop***:

```
@{ int maxPlayCount = Model.artist.Max(x=> x.playcount); }
```

And, then just get the value from this variable:

```
   ...aria-valuemax="@maxPlayCount"...
```

Comment: The model probably doesn't have a `Max` method, I think that you mean `Model.artist.Max`.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using it in a loop, you would want to calculate the value once and use it in the loop (to avoid an O(n*n) performance). You can add a property for it in the model:

```
public int MaxPlayCount { get; private set; }
```

Then set it in the model constructor after you have set the `artist` property:

```
MaxPlayCount = artist.Max(a => a.playcount);
```

In the markup get the value from the model:

```
... aria-valuemax="@Model.MaxPlayCount" ...
```